# Copy value with all hidden decimals

Tags: customization, shortcut

Is there a shortcut to copy an exact value with all the hidden decimals (those you see when calling the value in python) ?
I used to think that was what you were getting when hovering the value (without clicking) and hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> but apparently not.

If that's not possible, can we then display more decimals in the UI without changing units ?